# Adding Referencing outlet UITextView

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I am starting developping on xcode 7 and quite new in the domain.I have added a UITextView in my storyboard and do not succeed to add a "Referencing Outlet" from my UITextView to my View controller. Here is a screeshot of what I gen when I do a "Ctrl + link to my View".
I have another TextView where I did succeed to add it...
[image: adding Outlets]
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the view in storyboard is of the same class as your view controller? You can observe/update the class of the storyboard element in the identity inspector (righthand toolbar) while you have your view selected.

Comment: yes it is. I duplicate the Dictionary View component from the Translation View and it works for he Translation View .... :/(

Answer (score 0):

I succeed to Reference the Outlets by displaying the Assistant and doing a "CTRL + Link" to my .h file